# Pylint complains if super class accesses sub class attributes

Tags: python

I have a super class `Model` and a sub class `ThisModel`. `ThisModel` *must* have an attribute `name` and *can* have an attribute `description`. I want both of these attributes to be accessible by `Model`.

This is the code

```py
class Model:
    def __init__(self):
        if self.name is not None:
            print(f"{self.name} loaded")
        if hasattr(self, "description"):
            print(f"Description: {self.description}.")

class ThisModel(Model):
    name = "BeautifulName"
    description = "This is a very interesting model."
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

model = ThisModel()
```

How do I write this code without Pylint complaining:

```
Instance of 'Model' has no 'name' member [3, 12]
Instance of 'Model' has no 'name' member [4, 22]
Instance of 'Model' has no 'description' member [6, 35]
```

I would like to avoid passing these attributes to the `super().__init__()` function, if possible because my actual code has a lot more attributes and a lot more `ThisModels` and things can get pretty messy pretty soon.

Comment: Apart from being inherited, `Model` is a class of its own. How can you expect it to work if its `__init__` method refer to a non-existent instance attribute?

Comment: Just assign `name` and `description` as None in the parent class. Your code wouldn't even really work as intended as you would more likely need something like `getattr(self, "name", None) is not None`.

Comment: @Tomerikoo It seems to be an abstract base class, meaning that only instances of subclasses should be instantiated. It's not an explicit Python concept, though.

Comment: Actually, it is: https://docs.python.org/3/library/abc.html